# Where to add post_max_size in php.ini?

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I am learning wordpress and i need to edit post_max_size in php.ini. I am using Wamp 3.0.6 64 bit in my local machine. php version is 5.6.25 . I need to change value of post_max_size in php.ini. when i opened that file via wamp control panel, i am not able to find post_max_size(it`s not there in php.ini). I searched everywhere, i am not able to find where i should create this value post_max_size=1024M. so what i need is a section name/line no or something where i can create post_max_size=1024M.

Answer (score 1):

If post_max_size doesn't exists, you can add it everywhere in php.ini file (e.g - on the end of the file)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to php, so this is nice info

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to write code in php.ini file then you can use this code in your wordpress theme functions.php file.

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
```